# Migrating a backbone.js SPA to ASP.NET mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, backbone.js, model-view-controller

I have a working backbone.js app that works with localstorage for data persistence. We would like to implement back-end with ASP.NET MVC. Can this be done in terms of reusing the backbone code, which has models, views fully implemented, and just change the source of data for backbone views?

Comment: More info about the way you handle localstorage with backbone would be required.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the project uses the localstorage plugin, migrating should consist simply of

- removing the plugin from the project
- adding `url` endpoints to your models & collections

Localstorage simply overwrites the `sync` method so by reverting it everything should work fine with an API.